# Brakes, rims or seatpole

Tags: mountain-bike, upgrades, bike-setup

I've recently changed my bike from a hardtail to a full sus.
The only thing I could afford was the new frame. so new frame old pats :)
now I have some more euros and a want to buy some new parts where to I start.

New brakes. With the new frame I can go at least 10km/h faster. I need more braking power...
this is the ones I have: Tektro Draco / Hydraulic Disc 160/F and 160/R Rotor

New wells to make the beast go faster...

this is the ones I have:
Rims - Araya TX-633 / D-Wall / white
Front Hub - Scott Disc Team
Rear Hub - Shimano FH-M475 L
Spokes - 15 G, stainless, black

New seat pole, those hydraulic to avoid constant adjustments to climb descent...

the new frame is a lapierre zesty 314 2011...

My friends say we do all mountain, I say we do very hard XC.

Any advice regarding the new materials, personal choice, etc... I'll be happy.
Thanks

Comment: The question is far too broad to receive a good answer and is a basically shopping recommendation which are off topic on most stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, better brakes have never increased my top speed, I would be happy with a fraction of your 10km/h increase, can you please tell us how it works for you?

I once joined a group of strangers I met on a ride. They had $5K bikes, I assumed I would never be able to keep up on my beat up 1995 hack. How wrong was I. See, I spent $200 bucks on a 2 day training course and knew how to ride (well, at least a lot better than I did), they spend 5K on their bikes and didn't.  That $200 was the best money I every spent.

If you ride is reliable, unless you have the skills of a world class rider, get some training/coaching.

Comment: Your experience is right, better brakes less speed. I've edited the question. Your advice is pretty good... better to wait for something to brake and replace it...

Comment: @user952887 -- If you wait for something to brake you're gonna be replacing stuff (the brakes) right and left.  I'd suggest you wait for something to break instead.